# Exporting progress from Google Play Games to iOS Game Center

Tags: ios, google-play-games

I used [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en) to connect to [Despicable Me: Minion Rush!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftDMHM&hl=en). Is there any way to export my progress to the [same game on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/despicable-me-minion-rush/id596402997?mt=8) (which can be connected to [iOS Game Center](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202097))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, exporting progress from Google Play Games to iOS Game Center is possible if the game can also connect to Facebook:

1. On your Android device (where the game progress is located), log in to Facebook (see screenshot below)
2. On your iPhone device,  log in to Facebook, and it will retrieve all game information.

[image]

Comment: If I have 2 Android Devices. Can I transfer the progress from one device to the other using the google account ?